# How to encrypt smarty template files

Tags: php, encryption, smarty

I need to encrypt the code of template file with extension tpl . How it possible to encrypt the non php files like .tpl,.xml etc.

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: i need to protect code..

Comment: From what? If you are worried that a site visitor might access those files directly by pointing their browser at them, the solution is not encryption, but moving the files into a directory that is not under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: you have to deliver the decryption key to use them anyway so they will allways get your source?

Comment: Do you fear internal or external intrusion? Meaning - if you fear that someone from outside steals your .tpls, keep them in a directory protected from external, http access (.htaccess could work for Apache). If from inside, then you've got a permissions problem at best and people problem at worst, neither of which is solvable by encryption.

Comment: I am in a developing of product using smarty and I like to protect all files in the product folder.

Answer (score 0):

ioncube is one solution to encrypt files. but its paid version.

Comment: I am using ioncube to encrypt code and test it in the server, But it is  not supporting and showing an error message like this (requires the ionCube PHP Loader to be installed by the site administrator)

Comment: You need to add ioncube dll file into   php.ini file.

Comment: How it possible in a remote server ?

Comment: I don't know how exactly but try this.http://selectall.wordpress.com/2007/11/01/how-to-change-php-configuration-on-public-shared-server/